# Detect when the drawer is closed while using MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

Is there any way we can detect when the drawer is closed by dragging the center container? I wish to perform certain actions everytime the drawer is closed..

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
-(void)setGestureCompletionBlock:(void(^)(MMDrawerController * drawerController, UIGestureRecognizer * gesture))gestureCompletionBlock;
```

to set a callback block to be notified when a gesture is completed. In this block, query the drawerController to know what is currently open.

```
/**
 Sets a callback to be called when a gesture has been completed.

 This block is called when a gesture action has been completed. You can query the `openSide` of the `drawerController` to determine what the new state of the drawer is.

 @param gestureCompletionBlock A block object to be called that allows the implementer be notified when a gesture action has been completed.
 */
```

Comment: in my App Delegate? Or in any View Controller that I am using the Drawer in?

Comment: Every time you will call this method, the callback will be replaced. So AppDelegate sounds good ;)

Comment: Any idea what the Swift version would be?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift :(

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you explain please how can I use this in the App delegate?

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use following helper methods to detect MMDrawerController state.

**For Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)isLeftOpen {
    return (self.mm_drawerController.openSide == MMDrawerSideLeft);
}

- (BOOL)isRightOpen {
    return (self.mm_drawerController.openSide == MMDrawerSideRight);
}
```

**For Swift-3.x**

```
func isLeftOpen() -> Bool {
    return mm_drawerController.openSide == .left
}

func isRightOpen() -> Bool {
    return mm_drawerController.openSide == .right
}.
```

**Source:** https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/issues/337

Answer (score 0):

Using Quentin's answer you can check for the drawer width on gesture completion as

```
    [self setGestureCompletionBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, UIGestureRecognizer *gesture) {
    if (drawerController.visibleLeftDrawerWidth == 0.0f) {
        // "perform certain actions"
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a callback whenever the drawer will be open and closed.

```
drawerController?.setDrawerVisualStateBlock({ (drawer, drawerSide, percentVisible) in
                print(percentVisible)
                if percentVisible > 0 && self.blackView.superview == nil {
                    //drawer opened
                                }
                                if percentVisible == 0 {
                                    //drawer closed
                                }
            })
```

Note: percentVisible will be 0 when drawer will be closed and 1 when the drawer will be opened.