# MMDrawerController: detect menu close action or swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

I want to detect when the menu is closed. I found this SO solved [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518879/detect-when-the-drawer-is-closed-while-using-mmdrawercontroller). In the comments of the accepted answer, they say that this method:

```
-(void)setGestureCompletionBlock:(void(^)(MMDrawerController * drawerController, UIGestureRecognizer * gesture))gestureCompletionBlock;
```

have to be in the `App delegate` in order to be notified when the menu is closed. I putted this function in my App delegate, and in it's implementation I made a `NSLog(@"menu closed");` but nothing is printed in my console and the function is not fired when I close the menu.

Can anyone explain me please how can I detect that the menu is closed? (Based on the given answer or if you have another one)

**Edit:**

In the storyboard, I have an UINavigationController linked to an UIViewController having as type the MMDrawerController (`myVCMMdrawerController`), then I have also `myCenterVC`, the `leftVC` and the `rightVC`. In the `myVCMMdrawerController` `viewDidLoad` this is what I do:

```
MyCenterVC * centerVC = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myCenterVC"];
    centerVC.drawerController = self;

    LeftVC * leftVC = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftVC"];
    leftVC.drawerController = self;

    self.centerViewController = centerVC;
    self.leftDrawerViewController = leftVC;


    self.showsShadow = false;
    //[self setMaximumLeftDrawerWidth:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width animated: true completion: nil];

    //enable gesture
    self.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll;
    self.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll;
    [self closeDrawerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

In `myCenterVC` I make the actions to display the menu in IBActions like this:

```
[self.drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

here's the code that works for me :

**Swift 3.0+**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let leftDrawer = UIViewController()
    leftDrawer.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let centerDrawer = UIViewController()
    centerDrawer.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

let mainContainer = MMDrawerController(center: centerDrawer, leftDrawerViewController: leftDrawer)

mainContainer?.openDrawerGestureModeMask = .panningCenterView
mainContainer?.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = .panningCenterView

mainContainer?.setGestureCompletionBlock({ (drawer, gesture) in
    if drawer?.openSide != .left {
        print("Drawer Closed")
    }else {
        print("Drawer Opened")
    }
})

window?.rootViewController = mainContainer
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
```

}

You may have to ensure that you set

```
mainContainer?.openDrawerGestureModeMask = .panningCenterView
mainContainer?.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = .panningCenterView
```

and check if `drawer's openSide is left` else its closed.

**Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIViewController *leftDrawer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [[leftDrawer view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    UIViewController *centerDrawer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [[centerDrawer view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    MMDrawerController *mainDrawer = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerDrawer leftDrawerViewController:leftDrawer];
    mainDrawer.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
    mainDrawer.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;

    [mainDrawer setGestureCompletionBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, UIGestureRecognizer *gesture) {
        if (drawerController.openSide != MMDrawerSideLeft) {
            NSLog(@"Drawer Closed");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Drawer Opened");
        }
    }];

    self.window.rootViewController = mainDrawer;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the `objective-c` version?

Comment: Thank you! What if I create the drawer in an UIViewController? In the App Delegate I have created MMDrawerController *mainDrawer as a property, then in my UIViewController I set this mainDrawer with the one in the UIViewController. But it seems that the mainDrawer is not set. Have you an idea about this problem please? Thanks again

Comment: Can you provide code snippets of what you do to help me understand the problem please? @Llg

Comment: @Llg is there any good reason why you want to set it in another uiviewcontroller? its a common practise to initialise and set at the same time when the drawer controller is loaded into memory.

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence Tan. Actually I was searching for the same task. And this is working great.